# Can someone help me translate this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I was studying minna no nihongo 2 中級 and this sentence appeared in the middle of a text.
I don't quite understand it. Just the general idea.

> ロボコンによる教育は、生徒たちを精神的に成長させる人間教育**としても**注目されるようになった。

This "としても" confused me. 
What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of としても as "even if~". Here you should think of it as として+も. 「Noun+として」 has several meanings and in your example it means "as~" or "in the role of~". も here means "also".

The basic structure of the sentence is...

> 「XXは、YY**としても**注目されるようになった。」
>   "XX came to be noticed **also as** YY." / "XX came to draw attention **as** YY **as well**."